# Ordering distinct objects into lines and a circle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, contest-math, generating-functions

It is given that we have $n$ different objects and we want to arrange them in non-empty lines ,after that order these non-empty lines around a circle.How many ways are there in this question ? The given answer is $(2^n-1)!(n-1)!$ .It is given a hint such that use the composition of exponential generating functions.

What i thought : Without using the hint i thought that if there are $k$ lines where $k \in \{1,2,3...\}$ , G.F. of these lines is $(x/(1-x)) ,$ so we can say that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[x^n]\bigg(\frac{x}{1-x}\bigg)^kn!$$ ways there are to arrange these $n$ distinct object.Moreover , i know that if i have $m$ distinct object , i can arrange them around a circle $(m-1)!$ ways.However , icould not employ it in this question because i think that when the number of objects in a line are the same of one another , these lines may be seen as equal and do not allow to use this formula , so i will need Polyas' Enumeration.So , the question will be torturous..

Hence , i want help here... How can i use the hint ,i.e, E.G.F to solve this question and reach the given answer..

Thanks in advanced !!

$\mathbf{\text{Addentum:}}$ For $n=3$ ,the answer is $(2^3-1)(3-1)!=14$ according to @Marko Riedel's answer.However ,when i calculate it by brutal force ,i find different answer such that :

$1-)$ For only one line : $3! \times (1-1)!=6$ ways

$2-)$ For two lines : $3!\times C(1+2-1,1) \times (2-1)!=12$ ways

$3-)$ For three lines : $3!\times  (3-1)!=12$ ways

Result= $6+12+12=30$ , What am i missing here ? Why is it not equal to $14$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have using combinatorial classes as in *Analytic Combinatorics* by
Flajolet and Sedgewick the following class

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{F} = \textsc{CYC}(\textsc{SEQ}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

This gives the EGF

$$F(z) = \log\frac{1}{1-z/(1-z)}
= \log\frac{1-z}{1-2z}
= -\log\frac{1}{1-z} + \log\frac{1}{1-2z}.$$

Extracting coefficients we find

$$n! [z^n] F(z) = - n! \frac{1}{n} + n! \frac{2^n}{n}
= (n-1)! (2^n-1).$$

Here we have used the fact that $\textsc{CYC}(\mathcal{Q})$  has EGF
$\log\frac{1}{1-Q(z)}$ and $\textsc{SEQ}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Q})$  has EGF
$\frac{Q(z)}{1-Q(z)}$ which in turn follows from the fact that  the
cyclic group $C_m$ has order $m$ and the identity group $E_m$ has  order
$1$ so that the EGF of $\textsc{CYC}_{=m}(\mathcal{Q})$ is  $Q(z)^m/m$
and the EGF of $\textsc{SEQ}_{=m}(\mathcal{Q})$ is $Q(z)^m.$

This is labeled enumeration so no need to use PET.

Comment: This is page 104 of the 2009 edition (the online edition).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Very nice and instructive answer. (+1)

Comment: Thank you for the credit.

Comment: What you call lines is commonly called a block and contains labeled objects (balls). There are $n$ such balls in every configuration and they all have different labels. So there is no symmetry between blocks, they are pairwise distinct. I think my answer is the right one. You could document your calculations in the question text. For example with $n=3$ and three blocks all must be singletons and we get two different configurations due to cyclic symmetry.

Comment: With $n=3$ I get for three blocks two ways, for two blocks ${3\choose 2} \times 2$ for six ways and for one block, $3! = 6$ ways, for a total of fourteen as per the formula which gives the grand total.

Comment: MSE says to close this discussion. I think you are confusing three (the total number of elements) and three (the number of blocks). With $n=3$ and three blocks all the blocks are singletons and we get the two possibilities $([1], [2], [3])$ and $([1], [3], [2]).$